# Existence and Uniqueness of differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image: I was doing homework for my PDE class and I came across this question:]

To answer part (a) I wanted to relate the differential operator to a simple matrix operator and the Invertable Matrix Theorem. Say, if $Du=0$ has only the trivial solution, then $D$ maps to all of $C[a, b]$, but I realized that $D$'s null space is certainly not trivial as any constant function gives a $0$.

I understand that for part (b) if $u(x)=x$ is a solution to $Du=f$, then $u(x)=x+C$ is also a solution to $Du=f$ for any constant $C$, so the solution is not unique.

So how is it that an operator can have a non-trivial null space, but still map to, in my case, all of $C[a, b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working in an infinite dimensional setting, so injectivity need not be equivalent to surjectivity (to see an example of when this holds, look up the Fredholm alternative). To see that it's onto, let $f\in C([a,b]),$ and consider $F(x)=\int_a^x f(s)\, ds.$ What does $D$ do to $F$?

And, you're correct, the solution is not unique. If $u$ solves $Du=f,$ then so does $u+c$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Wouldn't your example with $F(x)$ only hold if $f(x)$ is an integrable function? What happens if $f(x)$ is in $C[a, b]$ and the integral of $f(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it's integrable.